# Montecarlo Simulation using mob() algorithm (partykit package) to recover the count of the correctly identified models

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I am using the `mob()` function from `partykit` package and I am getting some problems when parsing the obtained model.

My main aim is to check *approximately* how large a sample size needs to be in order to detect the real
structure of a data generating process (DGP) when breaks are present.

The code below performs a Montecarlo simulation of data with breaks and tries to identify if the break was captured by the M-fluctuation test or not.

More specifically, I want to make a count on the number of times over the total number of simulations (`nreps`) that the model actually captures the DGP, conditional on a fixed sample size (`N`) to get a feeling of how many data should I need to capture the real DGP.

At the end of the code, you can see the list that I get out of my simulations. The problem is that I cannot recover the information displayed on the console.

Additionally, I have some doubts about how to make the count of the "correctly identified models". For now, what I have in mind is to count as positive if the model has a break into the correct variable (`z1`) at the specified region (`z1>0`) with some tolerance into the break region for example if the break is at `z1>0.1` or `z1>-0.4` it is also valid as a positive for me. Therefore, is there any simple way of counting the models that have the stated characteristics?

I hope my example is clear enough for you to help me out. Thank you a lot in advance.

#### Simulate model

1. Ingredients to generate the DGP.

```
library("partykit")
library(data.table)   ## optional, but what I'll use to coerce the list into a DT
library(future.apply) ## for parallel stuff
plan(multisession)    ## use all available cores

#sample size
N <- 300
#coeficients
betas <- list()

betas$b0 <- 1

betas$b1_up   <- 2.4
betas$b1_down <- 2

betas$b2_up   <- 2.4
betas$b2_down <- 2

#mob() ingredients
ols_formula <- y ~ x1 + x2 | z1 + z2
# the ""0 +"" --->  supress the 'double' interecept
ols <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ...) {lm(y ~ 0 + x)}
```

2. Function that generates the data and fit OLS using mob algorithm.

```
reg_simulation_mob <- function(...){
  #data
  data <- data.frame(
    x1 = rnorm(N),
    x2 = rnorm(N),
    z1 = rnorm(N),
    z2 = rnorm(N),
    e  = rnorm(N))
  
  #dependent variable
  data$y <-   betas$b0 + with(data,  ifelse(z1>0,
                         betas$b1_up   * x1 + betas$b2_up   * x2 ,
                         betas$b1_down * x1 + betas$b2_down * x2 ) 
                        + e )
  
  
    #Estimate mob()-OLS
  ols_mob <- mob(ols_formula,
                 data = data, 
                 fit = ols)
  
  # return(ols$coefficients)
  return(ols_mob)
}
```

3. Montecarlo simulation (only 2 trials) of the above-described setup.

```
# N repetitions
nreps <- 2

## Parallel version
results  <- future_lapply(1:nreps, reg_simulation_mob, future.seed = 1234L)
```

#### Obtained result

As you can see below in the first trial (`results[[1]]`), the model finds the correct break but in the second (`results[[2]]`) it fails to find it.

```
> results
[[1]]
Model-based recursive partitioning (ols)

Model formula:
y ~ x1 + x2 | z1 + z2

Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] z1 <= 0.00029: n = 140
|       x(Intercept)          xx1          xx2 
|          0.9597894    1.7552122    2.1360788 
|   [3] z1 > 0.00029: n = 160
|       x(Intercept)          xx1          xx2 
|          0.9371795    2.4745728    2.5087608 

Number of inner nodes:    1
Number of terminal nodes: 2
Number of parameters per node: 3
Objective function: 422.2329

[[2]]
Model-based recursive partitioning (ols)

Model formula:
y ~ x1 + x2 | z1 + z2

Fitted party:
[1] root: n = 300
    x(Intercept)          xx1          xx2 
        1.015224     2.175625     2.200746  

Number of inner nodes:    0
Number of terminal nodes: 1
Number of parameters per node: 3
Objective function: 422.3085
```

In the picture below, you can observe the structure of the list `results`, where I cannot find the information displayed on the console (i.e. number of nodes, parameters, threshold values, etc..)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend to use the `lmtree()` function and not vanilla `mob()`. The former is faster, comes with better defaults for printing and plotting, and has more options for predictions.

Second, I recommend that you consult the `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")` which explains how `party` objects are constructed and which classes and methods are involved.

Third, to determine which variable (if any) was used for splitting in the root node it is probably of interest to extract the results from all parameter instability tests. There is a dedicated `sctest()` (structural change test) method for obtaining this:

```
library("strucchange")
sctest(results[[1]], node = 1)
##                     z1        z2
## statistic 4.072483e+01 6.1762164
## p.value   5.953672e-07 0.9153013
sctest(results[[2]], node = 1)
##                   z1         z2
## statistic 12.2810548 10.1944484
## p.value    0.2165527  0.4179998
```

The corresponding `partysplit` object for the `$split` (if any) in the root `$node` is probably easiest to extract manually:

```
results[[1]]$node$split
## $varid
## [1] 4
## 
## $breaks
## [1] 0.0002853492
## 
## $index
## NULL
## 
## $right
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $prob
## NULL
## 
## $info
## NULL
## 
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "partysplit"
results[[2]]$node$split
## NULL
```

The variable id pertains to the order of the variables in:

```
names(results[[1]]$data)
## [1] "y"  "x1" "x2" "z1" "z2"
```

Finally, as for the question *what* to evaluate: Everything depends on identifying the correct variable for splitting. If this is done correctly, then the split point estimates converge fast to the true values, and then the parameter estimates also converge. See for example our recent arXiv paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10179) which contains a larger simulation study and also provides replication code.

Therefore, typically, I either evaluate the probability of selecting the correct variable in the first split. Or alternatively I look at the RMSE of the estimated vs.true coefficients *for each observation*.

***Update:*** Beyond the root node you can use `nodeapply()` to extract information from various nodes. However, I do not recommend to evaluate all splits because it becomes increasingly difficult to match which estimated split matches which of the true splits. Instead, we often assess how similar the fitted partition is compared to the true partition, e.g., using the adjusted Rand Index. Again, you can find an example for the in the arXiv paper mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your kind answer professor @AchimZeileis. I did read what you suggested to me and it helped me a lot to better understand the `party` objects. However, I have one last question, and I took the freedom of editing my question with an extended example that should illustrate my problem and my desired output. Thank you again.

Comment: I've added a few updated comments in my response. Note, however, that such spaghetti questions that never end might be useful for you but are (a) typically hard to answer and (b) less useful for other readers. Hence it is recommended to ask focused questions about a specific problem that is likely to have a precise answer. See the guide for asking questions for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the update in your answer, professor @AchimZeileis. Also, my apologies for the mess in the last edit on my original question. I've modified it to keep your answer still valid, and additionally, I added an extended answer to my own question that I hope could be useful to other users in the future. Most of the code and figures were taken (and cited) from the [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10179) you mentioned. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is longer and more complex than what toy would usually post in a single question/answer on SO. It would be better to break such discussions down into several questions in the future. For this question I would recommend to leave things as they are but accept one of the two answers so that the question is marked resolved here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the reference that professor @AchimZeileis provided in his article (https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10179), and it is devoted to the second part of my original question, which was regarding the question: ***How to count the correctly specified models (trees)?***

## The short answer.

The article divides the problem into two different types of data generating process (DGP). In the first one, the data has only one break in one variable ("*stump*" case), and the authors count the number of correctly identified models based on the number of times that the M-fluctuation test identified correctly the variable that was generating the break (just one real break in one variable and 9 noisy candidates to be splitting variable with no break). The second DGP was a model with two breaks (*"tree"* case), and they used the [Adjusted Rand Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) (ARI) to assess the performance of the model as a metric of the similarity of the real tree to the predicted one.

## The <s>very</s> long answer.

Let's break down the [ARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) for 6 different illustrative possible trees that can be obtained at different sample sizes. The code used here is highly based on the supplemental material of the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10179) recommended by @AchimZeileis.

### Data generating process: Tree structure

The real dgp has 2 breaks, as illustrated in the picture below. The first one is generated by the variable `z2` and the second one by `z1`. In the snippet of the code below, delta is equal to 1. The threshold value for the first break (depending on `z2`) is equal to 0.3, and  the threshold value for the second break (depending on `z1`) is equal to -0.3 (the values can be seen in the object `xi = c(-0.3, 0.3)`)

[image: Figure from]

```
#function from https://arxiv.org/src/1906.10179v1/anc

dgp_tree <- function(nobs = 1000, delta = 1, xi = c(-0.3, 0.3),  
                     sigma = 1, seed = 7,  
                     changetype = "abrupt",
                     variation = "all",
                     beta0 = NULL, beta1 = NULL)
{
  # check input values
  if(variation != "all") stop("variation can only be set to 'all' in dgp_tree")
  if(changetype != "abrupt") stop("changetype can only be abrupt in dgp_tree")
  if(!is.null(beta0) | !is.null(beta1)) warning("values for beta0 or beta1 are ignored since variation='all' for dgp_tree")
  
  set.seed(seed)
  
  if(length(xi)==1){
    xi1 <- xi2 <- xi
  } else {
    xi1 <- xi[1]
    xi2 <- xi[2]
  }
  
  z1 <- runif(nobs,-1,1)
  z2 <- runif(nobs,-1,1) 
  z3 <- rnorm(nobs, 0, 1)
  z4 <- rnorm(nobs, 0, 1)
  z5 <- rnorm(nobs, 0, 1)
  z6 <- rnorm(nobs, 0, 1)
  z7 <- rnorm(nobs, 0, 1)
  z8 <- runif(nobs, -1, 1)
  z9 <- runif(nobs, -1, 1)
  z10 <- runif(nobs, -1, 1)
  
  id <- numeric(length(z1))
  
  x <- runif(nobs, min = -1, max = 1)
  
  beta0 <- delta * (-1)^(z1<xi1) * 0^(z2<xi2)
  beta1 <- delta * (-1)^(z2>=xi2)
  
  id <- 1 + (z2>=xi2) + (z2>=xi2)*(z1>=xi1)
  
  mu <- beta0 + beta1 * x
  
  y <- rnorm(nobs, mu, sigma)
  d <- data.frame(y = y, x = x, 
                  z1 = z1, z2 = z2, z3 = z3, z4 = z4, z5 = z5, z6 = z6, z7 = z7, z8 = z8, z9 = z9, z10 = z10,
                  beta0 = beta0, beta1 = beta1, mu = mu, sigma = rep.int(sigma, times = length(y)), id = id)
  
  return(d)
}
```

### The [Adjusted Rand Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index)

Among the functions included in the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10179), there is one to compute the [ARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index), and it is listed below to be used in the following examples. It resembles almost exactly letter by letter the notation used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index).

```
# function to compute adjusted Rand Index from https://arxiv.org/src/1906.10179v1/anc
adj_rand_index <- function(x, y) {
  tab <- table(x, y)
  a <- rowSums(tab)
  b <- colSums(tab)
  
  M <- sum(choose(tab, 2))
  N <- choose(length(x), 2)
  A <- sum(choose(a, 2))
  B <- sum(choose(b, 2))
  
  c(ARI = (M - (A * B) / N) / (0.5 * (A + B) - (A * B) / N))
}
```

### Simulating the data

```
library(partykit)
library(future.apply) ## for parallel stuff
plan(multisession)    ## use all available cores

ols_formula <- y ~ x | z1 + z2 +z3 +z4 + z5 +z6 +z7+ z8 +z9 +z10
ols <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ...) {lm(y ~ 0 + x)} 

sim_ari <- function(n){
  tree_data  <- dgp_tree(nobs = n)
  
  ols_mob    <- mob(ols_formula,
                    data = tree_data,
                    fit = ols)
  
  prednode   <- predict(ols_mob , 
                        type = "node")
  
  cross_table <- table(prednode,tree_data$id)
  ari         <- adj_rand_index(prednode, 
                        tree_data$id)
  
  print(n)
  print(ari)
  return(
    list(
      ols_mob = ols_mob,
      cross_table = cross_table,
      ari=ari, 
      data = tree_data)
  )
}


n_levels <- c(55,  ## no break
              87,  ## only one break
              123, ## Correct structure, but poor performance  
              199, ## Nested break in second leaf
              667, ## Additional break in first leaf
              5000 ## Perfect model
              )

ari <- future_lapply(n_levels, sim_ari, future.seed = 1234L)
```

## A Tale of Six Trees.

The following six cases are analyzed in terms of how the [ARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) can accurately capture the degree of similarity between the correct and the estimated tree. The key to compare the trees is `id`, which shows which leaf each observation should belong in the tree. For example, if an observation has an `id` value of `1`, it meets the requirements assigned to node number 2 in the figure above. On the other hand, if `id` is equal to 2, the observation should be assigned to node number 4 in the same picture. Finally, if `id` is equal to 3, it is assigned to node number 5. You can check this reasoning in the following line `id <- 1 + (z2>=xi2) + (z2>=xi2)*(z1>=xi1)`

#### The First Tree (n=55): No breaks

The first case analyzed corresponds when no breaks are identified. Here, in this case, the ARI is equal to 0.

```
##### First Tree (n=55): No break ####
ari[[1]][[1]]

## Fitted party:
##   [1] root: n = 55
## x(Intercept)           xx 
## -0.01309586   0.39291089  
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    0
## Number of terminal nodes: 1
## Number of parameters per node: 2
## Objective function: 95.58631
```

Here it is interesting to note that all the observations are assigned to the root node. Therefore, when crosstable the predicted nodes `prednode_1`, we see that all possible `id` values belong to the root node `[1]` of the predicted tree (basically, because there is no other option.) By using the function `adj_rand_index()`, you can check that this leads to an ARI equal to 0.

```
#data first tree (n=55)
data_1 <- ari[[1]][[4]]
#predicted node first iteration
data_1$prednode_1     <- predict(ari[[1]][[1]], type = "node")
#Cross table
with(data_1, table(prednode_1  ,id))

##             id
## prednode_1  1   2  3
##          1  37  7 11

#adj_rand_index
ari[[1]][[3]]
```

#### The second tree (n=87): Just one break identified

This case is interesting because it partially identifies the tree's structure (i.e., the break on `z1` is missing).

```
##### Second Tree (n=87): Extra partition in node[5] ####
ari[[2]][[1]]

# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] z2 <= 0.29288: n = 57
# |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |           0.133293     1.082701 
# |   [3] z2 > 0.29288: n = 30
# |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |          0.2598309   -1.8014133 
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    1
# Number of terminal nodes: 2
# Number of parameters per node: 2
# Objective function: 122.0116
```

Additionally, we can check that when crosstable the predicted and the real nodes, we see that some observations meet the criteria even in this non-perfect tree. Meaning there are `57` observations correctly assigned to the first node and `9` that were correctly assigned to the second branch. Finally, `30` where misassigned because the last node was not identified at all. This lead to an ARI equal to `0.8577366`, which is a huge improvement from the first tree.

```
#data second iteration (n=87)
data_2 <- ari[[2]][[4]]
#predicted node first iteration
data_2$prednode_2     <- predict(ari[[2]][[1]], type = "node")
#Cross table
with(data_2, table(prednode_2  ,id))
#             id
# prednode_2  1  2  3
#          2 57  0  0
#          3  1  9 20

#adj_rand_index
ari[[2]][[3]]

# > ari[[2]][[3]]
#       ARI 
# 0.8577366
```

#### The third tree (n=123): Correct structure but poor performance

This case is interesting because it **does** recover the real tree structure, but it has worse performance than the last three that only partially identified its structure.

```
##### Third Tree (n=123): Correct structure but poor performance ####
ari[[3]][[1]]
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] z2 <= 0.07319: n = 60
# |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |         -0.1723388    1.1071878 
# |   [3] z2 > 0.07319
# |   |   [4] z1 <= -0.35485: n = 22
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |         -0.7166565   -0.6791717 
# |   |   [5] z1 > -0.35485: n = 41
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |          0.7096033   -0.8605967 
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    2
# Number of terminal nodes: 3
# Number of parameters per node: 2
# Objective function: 156.4397
```

Below we can see that when we crosstable predicted and real nodes, we see that `16` (`10 + 6`) observations were incorrectly classified, and this fact leads to an ARI of `0.6117612`.

```
#data third iteration (n=123)
data_3 <- ari[[3]][[4]]
#predicted node first iteration
data_3$prednode_3     <- predict(ari[[3]][[1]], type = "node")
#Cross table
with(data_3, table(prednode_3  ,id))
# id
# prednode_3  1  2  3
#          2  60  0  0
#          4   6 16  0
#          5  10  0 31

#adj_rand_index
ari[[3]][[3]]
# > ari[[3]][[3]]
#       ARI 
# 0.6117612
```

#### The fourth Tree: Forth Tree (n=199): Extra leaf at node `[5]`

The tree identified here deviated from the original because it has an extra leaf from `node[5]`, which is unexisting in the real data.

```
##### Forth Tree (n=199): Extra leaf at node[5] ####
ari[[4]][[1]]
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] z2 <= -0.19806: n = 79
# |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |         0.06455217   1.51512672 
# |   [3] z2 > -0.19806
# |   |   [4] z1 <= -0.27127: n = 44
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |         -0.4863122   -0.3860951 
# |   |   [5] z1 > -0.27127
# |   |   |   [6] z2 <= 0.17481: n = 23
# |   |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |   |         -0.1335096    0.2046050 
# |   |   |   [7] z2 > 0.17481: n = 53
# |   |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |   |          1.0868488   -0.0290925 
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    3
# Number of terminal nodes: 4
# Number of parameters per node: 2
# Objective function: 282.6727
```

Here the count of the crosstable of the real and predicted nodes is interesting because nodes `[6]` and `[7]` are inexistent in the real data, but they are getting observations that should, for example, be assigned to the node `[1]` (`23` and `7` observations respectively.) This misallocation diminished the ARI index down to `0.4649789`.

```
#data forth iteration (n=199)
data_4 <- ari[[4]][[4]]
#predicted node first iteration
data_4$prednode_4     <- predict(ari[[4]][[1]], type = "node")
#Cross table
with(data_4, table(prednode_4  ,id))
#             id
# prednode_4  1  2  3
#          2 79  0  0
#          4 16 27  1
#          6 23  0  0
#          7  7  0 46
#adj_rand_index
ari[[4]][[3]]
#     ARI 
# 0.4649789
```

#### The fifth Tree (n=667): Extra leaf at node `[2]`

This is another example of a tree with an incorrect structure where an extra leaf (based on a partition on `z5` which is incorrect(!)) is attached to the node `[2]`.

```
##### Fifth Tree (n=667): Extra leaf at node[2] ####
ari[[5]][[1]]
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] z2 <= 0.28476
# |   |   [3] z5 <= 0.76285: n = 322
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |         -0.1322881    0.9535337 
# |   |   [4] z5 > 0.76285: n = 96
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |          0.1686863    1.3878776 
# |   [5] z2 > 0.28476
# |   |   [6] z1 <= -0.32001: n = 89
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |         -0.9139858   -0.7957158 
# |   |   [7] z1 > -0.32001: n = 160
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |          0.7661154   -0.8656553 
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    3
# Number of terminal nodes: 4
# Number of parameters per node: 2
# Objective function: 927.9088
```

The crosstable from predicted and correct nodes shows us that most of the observations (`322`) that, in reality, belong to the first node `[1]` were assigned to the predicted node `[3]`. Finally, this poor structure leads to an ARI of `0.6932132`.`

```
#data third iteration (n=667)
data_5 <- ari[[5]][[4]]
#predicted node first iteration
data_5$prednode_5     <- predict(ari[[5]][[1]], type = "node")
#Cross table
with(data_5, table(prednode_5  ,id))
#              id
# prednode_5   1   2   3
#          3 322   0   0
#          4  96   0   0
#          6   0  89   0
#          7   3   3 154

#adj_rand_index
ari[[5]][[3]]
#     ARI 
# 0.6932132
```

#### The sixth tree (n=5000): The Golden Tree!

This final tree recovers the data perfectly, both in the tree structure and in allocating the observation to each leaf.

```
##### Sixth Tree (n=5000): Extra leaf at node[2] ####
ari[[6]][[1]]
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] z2 <= 0.29971: n = 3187
# |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |       -0.008719923  1.022232280 
# |   [3] z2 > 0.29971
# |   |   [4] z1 <= -0.30286: n = 609
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |         -0.9488846   -0.9813765 
# |   |   [5] z1 > -0.30286: n = 1204
# |   |       x(Intercept)           xx 
# |   |          1.0281410   -0.9565637 
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    2
# Number of terminal nodes: 3
# Number of parameters per node: 2
# Objective function: 6992.848
```

Here we can see from the crosstable of the predicted and real nodes that it allocates *perfectly* each observation where it does belong, leading to an ARI equal to `1`.

```
#data sixt iteration (n=5000)
data_6 <- ari[[6]][[4]]
#predicted node first iteration
data_6$prednode_6     <- predict(ari[[6]][[1]], type = "node")
#Cross table
with(data_6, table(prednode_6  ,id))
#               id
# prednode_6    1    2    3
#          2 3187    0    0
#          4    0  609    0
#          5    0    0 1204

#adj_rand_index
ari[[6]][[3]]
# ARI 
#  1
```

#### The conclusions.

Some important takeaways can be recovered from the illustration above.

1.- The [ARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) is useful to assess the degree of similarity of a predicted tree that can have a very different structure from the real tree in the data generating process.

2.- Recover the tree's correct structure does not lead to an [ARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) equal to one.

3.- Incorrect trees not necessarily will an [ARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) equal to zero.

#### A final Simulation.

To conclude, here is a small simulation to see how the [ARI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) index behaves when the sample size increases.

```
### Final simulation 
n_levels <-seq(from= 10, to= 2000, by= 5)

ari  <- lapply(n_levels, sim_ari)

ari_models<- function(i){
  ari  <- ari_sim[[i]]$ari
  n    <- nobs(ari_sim[[i]]$ols_mob)  
  return(
    list(ari = ari , n= n )
  )
}


ari_n_list <- lapply(1:length(ari_sim), ari_models)
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(ari_n_list), nrow=length(ari_n_list), byrow=T))

colnames(df) <- c("ARI" , "N")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(N)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = ARI, colour = "ARI"))
```

[image]